# CSS3 Fonts lack anti-alias and smoothness in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, font-face

I've checked many threads regarding this and have tried many things to get this issue to resolve but it still persists.

I'm currently revamping a website using CSS3 fonts, moving away from Cúfon which was done be the previous developer for something more code light and modern.

I'm using CSS3 @font-face to call the font family. The code I'm using is generated by Font Squirrel. So, my CSS call is like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'helveticaneuelight';
src: url('fonts/helveticaneue_lt-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/helveticaneue_lt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/helveticaneue_lt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/helveticaneue_lt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/helveticaneue_lt-webfont.svg#helveticaneuelight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And in that CSS file when applying it to an element it looks like this:

```
body {
line-height: 130%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
font-size:80%;  /*-- Enables font size scaling in MSIE  --*/
font-family:'helveticaneuelight', Helvetica, Serif;
background-color: #000000;
color: #5b5b5b;
letter-spacing: 0;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='themeimages/HIEfix.png',sizingMethod='crop');
zoom: 1;
}
```

The "filter" and "zoom" properties are a hack that make the font look slightly better in IE but the problem is that in all browsers except IE the font looks like it should be as intended but in IE it's thinner and looks more aliased. The actual page in question is here: 
http://solanghansen.com/site/services/

This site isn't 100% finished so there's some other glitches I'm aware of in there as well.

The current site on that same page using Cúfon is here:
http://solanghansen.com/services.php

With that page the menu is text as image and the rest of the text in Cúfon. The client likes that but obviously that's not the "proper" way to do it, especially as the new version is responsive and has more jQuery stuff going on.

Has anyone encountered this before? It's likely something easy but I'm not finding the answer at the moment!

Comment: See these three screenshots:

http://www.jjdworks.com/clients/sandh/Services_Chrome_Mac.png

http://www.jjdworks.com/clients/sandh/Services_MozillaFirefox_Mac.png

http://www.jjdworks.com/clients/sandh/Services_IE10_PC.png

Remember to zoom in 100% on those when viewing.